# LINQ - query does not return an object from a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects and I need to execute a LINQ query on it to find some specific object.

```
class MyClass
{ 
    int id;
    int someOtherIdbutNotUnique;
}

var ls = myObjectList.Where(x => x.id==specificId 
                          && x.someOtherIdbutNotUnique == someOtherSpecificId)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

But this query does not return a MyClass object. And also, how should I change the query to get list of MyClass objects that fulfill the given condition. At the same time, would like to know if there is any good LINQ tutorial where I can start from the scratch.

Comment: Create a small sample that reproduces the problem. We don't know what `myObjectList` is and `FirstOrDefaults` is not a known extension method. You also may want to explain what _does_ get returned by that code, or what `ls` is and what you expect it to be.

Comment: sorry..."myobjectList" is a list of "MyClass" objects. hope it's clear now

Comment: @CodeCaster `FirstOrDefaults` may not be known, but it can be assumed that `FirstOrDefault` was meant. specially when he says "But this query does not return a MyClass object"

Comment: so possibly in _myObjectList_ not element satisfying the conditions

Comment: @Callum we're not here to guess. It's OP's responsibility to provide a relevant example that compiles and reproduces the issue. For all we know he _does_ have a `FirstOrDefaults` extension method that returns a string.

Comment: Once again sorry....yes, it's a typo...what I meant was "FirstOrDefault"

Comment: @CodeCaster ... just no. If he doesn't know enough about it, then you can't expect him to get it all right.... why post a question if he already knows....

Comment: Anyway, @nidarshanifernando that code should work. Make sure that your list is populated first. and the `ls` isn't `null`. Any extension method ending in `OrDefault` means it could return `null`.

Comment: @Callum then I suggest you and OP go read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) once again. You can't post code that somewhat resembles the original problem and hope the reader figures it out.

Comment: FirstOrDefaults() is not an extension method but FirstOrDefault is.

Comment: If you are using FirstOrDefault and not getting result then condition is not matching hence you are not getting result.

Comment: If you want to get a list of objects that satisfies the above condition, skip `FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

LINQ extension methods take predicates to filter the list by. `Where`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault` (to name but a few) all take the same predicate.

Some Lambda expression to filter the list by.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Other {get;set;}
}

// myClasses is a populated list <-- this needs to be checked.
var result = myClasses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == specificId && x.Other == specificOther);
```

`Result` should now contain either a single `MyClass` instance or a `null`.

If you omit the `OrDefault()` then your code will throw an error if it can't find an Instance that matches the predicate.

If the predicate returns several items, then `First` will pick the first item. If you swap `First` to `Single` and the predicate returns several items, it will throw an exception.

---

**Things to check**

1. The list you are performing the query against has a list of instances.
2. The variables `specificId` and `specificOther` have values that exist in the list. The last thing you want to do is be wondering why it isn't returning anything, when actually it is doing exactly what you asked for and that the reason for failing is the values you were using to query with where wrong.

Comment: @joe yeah, i'm not entirely sure how to word it to be honest.