# Pull field from another table in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio

am just learning MVC and this is my first project.  What I am creating is a help desk for my company.  Right now I am working on the Add Tickets.

The way I am trying to get it to work is we have a ticket category like 'Microsoft Office' that a user chooses.  Each category has a Technician attached to it.  So when the user chooses the category it is supposed to autoassign the technician.  Here is the code I currently have:

```
public ActionResult Create(NewTicket newTicket)
    {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        TicketNote ticketNote = new TicketNote();

        try
        {
            Guid ticketGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();

            //Add Ticket
            ticket.TicketId = ticketGuid;
            //ticket.TicketNumber = 
            ticket.CategoryId = newTicket.CategoryId;
            ticket.OpenUserId = new Guid("999600FC-709E-4463-84AD-D26894BABB54");
            ticket.OpenDate = DateTime.Now;
            ticket.TechnicianId = from c in db.Categories
                                  where c.CategoryId == newTicket.CategoryId
                                  select c.PrimaryTechnicianId;
            ticket.TicketStatusId = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
            //ticket.CloseDate = DateTime.Now;
            tickets.Insert(ticket);
            tickets.Commit();

            //Add Ticket Note
            ticketNote.TicketNoteId = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            ticketNote.TicketId = ticketGuid;
            ticketNote.TicketNoteDate = DateTime.Now;
            ticketNote.Note = newTicket.TicketNote;
            ticketNotes.Insert(ticketNote);
            ticketNotes.Commit();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //catch(Exception ex)
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is particular on this line (the rest works):

```
ticket.TechnicianId = from c in db.Categories
                                  where c.CategoryId == newTicket.CategoryId
                                  select c.PrimaryTechnicianId;
```

The error I keep getting is 'Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Guid' on the select statement in the above line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, this LINQ:

```
 from c in db.Categories where c.CategoryId == newTicket.CategoryId
                       select c.PrimaryTechnicianId;
```

will return `IEnumerable`, so in order to assign to `ticket.TechnicianId`, you should continue to call `First` or `Single`, something like this:

```
ticket.TechnicianId = (from c in db.Categories
                              where c.CategoryId == newTicket.CategoryId
                              select c.PrimaryTechnicianId).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you be overwriting the `TechnicianId`?

```
ticket.TechnicianId = from c in db.Categories
                                  where c.CategoryId == newTicket.CategoryId
                                  select c.PrimaryTechnicianId;
ticket.TechnicianId = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
```

The `select` just says which **fields** to pull out of the category object **but** will still return you an `IQueryable<T>`. In order to get `Guid`, you need to call `.First()` or `.Single()` afterwards to get 1 object out of the `IQueryable<T>`.

I advise calling `.Single()` because if you have a list of categories with more than 1 `CategoryId` then there is an error.

`First()` will bring you back a item from a list. `Single()` expects there to be only one item , if there isn't it will throw an error.

I recommend you read my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940862/linq-query-does-not-return-an-object-from-a-list-of-objects/29941146#29941146)

Comment: This second line was only there when I was testing and will comment it out.  I cannot even run it because I am getting the error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Guid>' to 'System.Guid' on the select line.